# Adding all columns in SELECT statement into group by undoes the grouping I want

Tags: sql, group-by, presto

I want to GROUP BY the supplier_so (so that there is only 1 line for each, and the quantities are just added up).  This query works just fine:

```
SELECT supplier_so, sum(CAST(qty AS int)) as qty
FROM table.name
where
item_code like 'XXX%'
and
doc_date = '05/28/2021'
group by supplier_so
```

but it doesn't give me all of the columns I want.  When I add in all of the columns I want into the SELECT statement it also makes me add them into the GROUP BY, and undoes the grouping by the supplier_so:

```
SELECT doc_date, doc_no, site, doc_type, supplier_so, item_code, item_description, sum(CAST(qty AS int)) as qty, item_class, source_filename
FROM table.name
where
item_code like 'XXX%'
and
doc_date = '05/28/2021'
group by supplier_so, doc_no, site, doc_type, doc_date, item_code, item_description, qty, item_class, source_filename
order by item_code
```

Answer (score 1):

You clearly have multiple values per supplier.  One way to fix this is to use aggregation functions:

```
select supplier_so, max(doc_date), max(doc_no), . . .
       sum(CAST(qty AS int)) as qty
FROM table.name
where item_code like 'XXX%' and
      doc_date = '05/28/2021'
group by supplier_so
order by max(item_code)
```

Comment: That worked, thank you!  Could you explain why my query was undoing the supplier_so group by?

Comment: @Helpplease . . . Your second query works fine . . . you just added a bunch of other columns to the `group by` so it did not do what you wanted.